# adding a set of integers to Redis using phpredis

Tags: php, serialization, redis, php-7, phpredis

I am trying to add a SET of integers (`sadd`) via PHPRedis extension.

```
 $Client->sadd('key',1,2,3);
```

or
`call_user_func_array([$Client,'sadd'],[1,2,3]);`

In the monitor I get:

```
"SADD" "key" "i:1" "i:2" "i:3"`
```

Which means it is serialized.
How do I do it so it is not serialized and inserted into Redis like if I do it from command line.
Monitor:

```
"SADD" "key" "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: An interesting discussion on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718263/php-redis-is-there-a-way-to-store-php-object-in-redis-without-serializing-it - without a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was some negligence on my part.
In my connection I set by default

```
$Redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP);
```

So all I have to do is use in the connection code (which is the default)

```
$Redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, Redis::SERIALIZER_NONE)
```