# PHP XML String to complex PHP Class

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, zend-framework2

I am currently trying to rebuilt some java code in PHP. 
The code builds XML from a given object and sends XML requests to a backend. The backend delivers the response. Now I want to convert the XML response in a php object of a certain complex class. I used SimpleXml to convert the string to the class XmlResponse but i can only access the getter and setter from the XmlResponse class and not the other class inside the XmlResponse Class.
In Java I simply use JAXB but I am not sure if something like this is possible. The the problem is, that the data tag can change from request to request, delivering other objects, depending on the request!

I am using the following setup :

- PHP 5.6 or 7
- Zend 2 or 3

Greetings!

At the end I want something like this :

```
<?php
    $responseObject = convertStringToObject($responseString, XMLResponse::class);
    $result = $responseObject->getResult();
    $data = $responseObject->getResult()->getData();
    $status = $responseObject->getResult()->getStatus();
    $user = $responseObject->getResult()->getData()->getUser()

?>
```

The Response looks like this :

```
<response>
    <transaction_id>1234</transaction_id>
    <result>
        <status>
            <code>1</code>
            <msg>Success</msg>
        </status>
        <data>
            <user>
                <fname>Jon</lname>
                <lname>Doe</lname>
                <birthday>1986-08-01 00:00:00</birthday>
            </user>
        </data>
    </result>
</response>
```

Now I have the following classes in PHP.

XmlResponse

```
class XmlResponse {

    public $result; #XmlResult Class
    public $transaction_id; #string

    public function getArrayCopy() {
      return get_object_vars($this);
    }

     //getter + setter

 }
```

XmlResult

```
class XmlResult {

    public $data; #XmlData Class
    public $status; #XmlStatus Class

    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return get_object_vars($this); 
    }

    //getter + setter

}
```

XmlStatus

```
class XmlStatus {

    public $code; #string
    public $msg; #string

    public function getArrayCopy() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    //getter + setter

}
```

XmlData

```
class XmlData {

    public $user; #User Class
    public $car; #Car Class
    public $member; #Member Class
    public $foo; #Foo Class

    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    //getter + setter

}
```

User

```
class User {

    public $fname; #string
    public $lname; #string
    public $birthday; #string

    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    //getter + setter

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using xpath to query your xml? --> http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best and easiest solution for me! There is a library called **Sabre** that supports converting objects to XML and XML to objects :
http://sabre.io/xml/

It comes up with some nice interfaces that you can implement within your object class, that controls the XmlSerialization and XmlDeserialization. So you define the mapping for **XML tags -> Object variables** and **Object variables -> XML tags** within you class. After that you only have to define the mapping of the XML tag to the object class and the object class to XML tag.

```
use Sabre\Xml\Service;
$xml = "<xml></xml>" #your xml as string
// For XML to object
$service->elementMap = [
    'XMLTAGNAME' => 'MyObject::class',
    'XMLTAGNAME' => 'MyObject2::class',
];
$service->parse($xml);

// For object to XML
$service->classMap = [
    'XMLTAGNAME' => MyObject::class,
    'XMLTAGNAME' => MyObject2::class,
];
$service->write("PARENTXMLTAGNAME", $object);
```

Within the class it will look something like this :

```
class MyObject implements XmlDeserializable, XmlSerializable {

    public $variable;

    function xmlSerialize(Writer $writer) {
        $writer->write([
            'variable' => $this->variable,
        ]);
    }

    static function xmlDeserialize(Reader $reader) {
        $object = new MyObject();
        $keyValue = \Sabre\Xml\Deserializer\keyValue($reader);
        if (isset($keyValue['variable'])) {
            $object->variable = $keyValue['variable'];
        }
        return $object;
    }
    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Installation :

```
`composer require sabre/xml`
```

API Documentation :

XmlSerialization : http://sabre.io/xml/reading/

XmlDeserialization : http://sabre.io/xml/writing/

Answer (score 0):

Is serialization something you are looking for. For example first match when I searched:

[How-to Serialize/Unserialize a SimpleXML Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970957/how-to-serialize-unserialize-a-simplexml-object)